# MySQL is there any way to easily decrease the value of a column by 20 for multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have about 23 000 records in my database and there are twenty duplicates from 4921 to 4940. I could easily delete the duplicates, but then my `id` column (auto-increment) value would be incorrect. So my question: is there a way to change the `id` column for records with `id` greater than 4940 without making thousands of queries?

EDIT: I realise the title is a little vague.... I'll edit it now.

Comment: This could be extremely dangerous if the keys you are changing are related to other records already.  YOu may destroy existing relationships.  having gaps in an ID field whose sole purpose is to be unique isn't a bad thing. The second you start adding meaning to that ID other than it needs to be unique, you're asking for trouble.  SO the question is why is the auto-increment value incorrect?  What happens over time if you need to delete records? you'll have gaps then, so are they incorrect as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why you'd want to do this, or why it matters.

Or is this a "smart key" of some kind?

I would imagine that you could easily do it with:

```
UPDATE table
SET key=key-20
WHERE key>4940;
```

Comment: Thank you! It's been a while since I've had to deal with database tasks in my team and I'm a bit rusty with my sql. Thank you again :)